# Logcat not show respon showing log com.android.studio E/AndroidLogcatService: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

Tags: android, adb, logcat

[image: logcat]

can someone got problem like me the logcat show error com.android.studio E/AndroidLogcatService: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException

restart android studio
invalidate cache still not working
use emulator or use real device with usb or wifi still same

update adb not fixed it
my adb already new on version [image: adb]
i dont know how to fix it now

adb logcat working on cmd
[image: adb logcat on cmd]

but i need adb logcat on android because cant instal apk directly from android studio show message waiting device to online

Comment: Does `adb logcat` work from command line?

Comment: yes adb logcat working on command line